# How to create a event form similar to fb in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a event form something like this o exactly like this, is there a library for this kind of a event form or how can i do this? Sorry im newbie in android. I've creating a event app for android. Thank you for any help.

https://ibb.co/bwnTLv

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez." Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use recyclerview Horizontal
then use cardview to design your card as per your design

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

here is the demo of both the things.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You can try gradle files like the one on this link. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4247 it's easier and will have a better UI. Or just go to,  https://www.android-arsenal.com to search for more. Thanks.